# Asymptotic expansion of $(\text{log}(1+x))^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics

How can I find asymptotic expansion of the function $(\text{log}(1+z))^2$ with respect to the asymptotic scale $\{z^{-m}, z^{-n}\text{log}(z), z^{-p}\text{log}^2(z), m,n,p=0,1,2,...\}$ while $z\rightarrow\infty$, $|\text{arg}(z)|<\pi$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $\log^2$ is ambiguous.  Do you mean $\log(\log(1+z))$ or $(\log(1+z))^2$?

Comment: I mean $(\text{log}(1+z))^2$.